# Using Windows MySQL Workbench 8.0 with Mariadb and PAM authentication

Tags: mysql, windows, mariadb, mysql-workbench, pam

I'm currently attempting to get the latest version of MySQL Workbench for Windows to connect to Mariadb v 5.6.10 running on CentOS. With a user authenticated using MySQL's built-in authentication, I can connect fine (I get an incompatibility message, but I can still connect and run queries), but if I try to connect using a PAM-authenticated user, it complains about a missing DLL:

`Authentication plugin 'dialog' cannot be loaded.`

With `procmon`, I was able to determine that it is looking for `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\dialog.dll`

Under the pre-8 versions of MySQL Workbench, you could simply extract the DLL from the Windows MariaDB distribution and copy it to the appropriate directory, but this doesn't work with Workbench 8.0 (I tried with the latest Mariadb Windows distribution and it complained about an API incompatibility with the version of `dialog.dll` I copied in). Are there any DLLs that will allow this to work? Any other workaround?

Comment: use this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_plugin-dir option as descrubed in the documentation

Comment: I don't see how that would help; that's for the MySQL command line, not MySQL Workbench (command line works fine).

Comment: Also, the problem is not the location, since I already know where it's looking; it's the DLL itself.

Comment: If there was a problem, it should be an error or a system and sorry for my first comment, i thought that it was valid also for workbench

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to change the sever configuration and force the client to use mysql_clear_password instead of dialog. However this will not work if PAM service requires multiple questions or challenge-responses.

```
[mariadb]
....
pam_use_cleartext_plugin
```

Comment: Hmm, an interesting thought, but when I tried it, I get this message from the client:

`Authentication plugin 'mysql_clear_password' cannot be loaded: plugin not enabled`.

Is there something else I need to do?